# very confused working on json in swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I get totally very confused working with JSON in swift.
according to Apple dec: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

```
/*
    {
        "someKey": 42.0,
        "anotherKey": {
        "someNestedKey": true
        }
    }
*/
```

What is a well-formed way to format this `jsonWithObjectRoot` json string?
I tried serval ways but n success.

so subsequently, these methods can access it.

```
if let dictionary = jsonWithObjectRoot as? [String: Any] {
    if let number = dictionary["someKey"] as? Double {
        // access individual value in dictionary
    }

    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        // access all key / value pairs in dictionary
    }

    if let nestedDictionary = dictionary["anotherKey"] as? [String: Any]     {
        // access nested dictionary values by key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json looks good. You need to parse it before casting to a [String:Any].

```
let jsonWithObjectRoot = "{ \"someKey\": 42.0, \"anotherKey\": { \"someNestedKey\": true } }"
let data = jsonWithObjectRoot.data(using:.utf8)!
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data)
    if let dictionary = json as? [String: Any] {
        if let number = dictionary["someKey"] as? Double {
            // access individual value in dictionary
        }

        for (key, value) in dictionary {
            // access all key / value pairs in dictionary
        }

        if let nestedDictionary = dictionary["anotherKey"] as? [String: Any]     
        { 
            // access nested dictionary values by key
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("Error parsing Json")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I think I misunderstood. So is jsonWithObjectRoot.data the .data is the method to encode jsonWithObjectRoot in json format and after JSONSerialization method  it encodes to dictionary, did I understand correctly?

Comment: No .data() method is converting from String to Data. Data describes a block of memory. The conversion from Data to parsed object is done by JSONSerialization.jsonObject(). The result of this can then be cast as a Dictionary. In general when you receive data from the web it is in the form of a Data class so you don't need to do the String Data conversion.

Comment: Thanks again. So the processes are json-> data(jsonWithObjectRoot.data)->dicktionary(JSONSerialization) ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I've edited my original code to include your dictionary parsing code to make it obvious where you process your dictionary.

Comment: Start with a String, convert it to Data, parse Data with JSONSerialisation, cast resultant object as Dictionary, process Dictionary

Comment: What makes JSONSerialisation cast into Dictionary but not a Set or Array? If I choose, can I cast it into  a set or array, or perhaps even tuples? and also when I try to access the Dictionary like dict["XYZ"] I get Type 'Any' has no subscript members because returns Any type, there seems to be something missing but I don't know what it is and how to correct it.

Comment: It would cast as an Array if the json represented an Array.